# Sql query is not supported old version in android

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Hi i have implemented this query below i have mention.

This query purpose two column in saved local database i have sent it amount. For that amount  which delivery charge it will be get.But old version first value only get it .but new version successfully update.Why i don't know it's not update old version.

Query:

```
mCursor = db.rawQuery("select ROUND(deliverycharge) from pincodedetails where ROUND(subtotal) <=( select ROUND(subtotal)  from pincodedetails where ROUND(subtotal)>="+price+" and resturantID="+selArgs+" LIMIT 1) and resturantID="+selArgs+" and ROUND(subtotal) >=( select ROUND(subtotal) from pincodedetails where ROUND(subtotal)<="+price+" and resturantID="+selArgs+" LIMIT 1)  order by ROUND(subtotal) LIMIT 1", null);
```

I think **LIMIT 1 is not supported in old version**.

Please give me solution for me?

```
public double getAllPincodeDetails(
            String dinein_restaurant_id,Double GetAllPrice ) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String selArgs = dinein_restaurant_id;
        Double price = GetAllPrice;
        String query = "select ROUND(delivarycharge) from pincodedetails where ROUND(subtotal) <=( select ROUND(subtotal)  from pincodedetails where ROUND(subtotal)>="+price+" and resturantID="+selArgs+" LIMIT 1) and resturantID="+selArgs+" and ROUND(subtotal) >=( select ROUND(subtotal) from pincodedetails where ROUND(subtotal)<="+price+" and resturantID="+selArgs+" LIMIT 1)  order by ROUND(subtotal) LIMIT 1";
        Log.i(this.toString(), "Message"+query);
        mCursor = db.rawQuery("select ROUND(delivarycharge) from pincodedetails where ROUND(subtotal) <=( select ROUND(subtotal)  from pincodedetails where ROUND(subtotal)>="+price+" and resturantID="+selArgs+" LIMIT 1) and resturantID="+selArgs+" and ROUND(subtotal) >=( select ROUND(subtotal) from pincodedetails where ROUND(subtotal)<="+price+" and resturantID="+selArgs+" LIMIT 1)  order by ROUND(subtotal) LIMIT 1", null);
        double delivarycharge = 0;
        if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) 
        {
            // Got first result
            delivarycharge = mCursor.getDouble(0);
         //System.out.println("***************"+mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex("totamount")));System.out.println("***************"+mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex("price")));
        }
//
        return delivarycharge;
    }
```

Comment: which version of Android precisely? and API?

Comment: 2.2 version and API 8

Comment: I got String query while running dubug .I copied and Sqllite database software put in that query .I got result perfectly in all version.but i can't get in emulator in new version.

Comment: Really? I have seen that there are limitations around the "LIMIT" keyword? - what software are you talking about above, sorry?

Comment: Sqllite database browser

Comment: Did you know that SQLite in API 8 is '3.6.19' or '3.6.22'? - could be useful

Comment: Please i can't understand can you let me know briefly?

Comment: All I know it that SQLite is not all that old... and at the time of API 8 (~2009) SQLite was missing some functionality.If you look in the answer I provided there is a link - it discusses the limitations of SQLite LIMIT keyword.

Comment: its in the answer, mismarked "SQL Lite  Documentation"..

Answer (score 0):

SQlite is simply a limited SQL implementation... it is designed for different purposes than larger DBMSs.

You will need to simplify the SELECT queries and do some of the processing in your Java code.

See here:  [SQL Lite Documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/docs.html)